# Having trouble creating a Reducer.mean in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, reduce, google-earth-engine

Hello I'm new to programming and I have to write a code for my MSc thesis that creates a tool that calculates cumulative changes in carbon stocks over time but I'm having trouble entering a Reducer mean in my code because I don't know what am I suppose to do. My code is fine but my tutor said that we need more years for our calculation to be in "real-time data", which means I have to calculate 20 years time period. But GEE has a memory exceeded problem so she said that a reducer will fix this problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.